# multiple levels of nesting component in JPA

Tags: hibernate

I know using hibernate mapping files we can nest one component inside another.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernaterecipes.chapter3">
<class name="Orders" table="BOOK_ORDERS">
<id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<component name="weekdayContact" class="Contact">
    <property name="recipient" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_RECIPIENT" />
    <component name="phone" class="Phone">
        <property name="areaCode" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_AREACODE" />
        <property name="telNo" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_TELEPHONE" />
    </component>
    <property name="address" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_ADDRESS" />
</component>
<component name="holidayContact" class="Contact">
    <property name="recipient" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_RECIPIENT" />
    <component name="phone" class="Phone">
        <property name="areaCode" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_AREACODE" >
        <property name="telNo" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_TELEPHONE" />
    </component>
    <property name="address" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_ADDRESS" />
</component>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

As per my understanding we cannot do the same with JPA.Is the understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding we can do the same with JPA.Is the understanding correct?

Yes and no. JPA 1.0 supports only properties which follows the rules for the [Basic annotation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html), meaning that it doesn't support other @Embedded. But JPA 2.0 supports it.

Comment: @parenon: I meant they are "properties", not "relationships".

Comment: @axtavt : Right, but properties is also misleading :-) For Java, a property can be something which is annotated with @ManyToOne, or @Embedded, or it can be a @Basic (like primitives + Timestamp, Date, ...). "Relationship between two classes of objects" would be accurate, as long as we don't read "relationship" like in Relational model.

Comment: @partenon: But the word "relationship" in JPA usually means "relationship between entities", i.e. `@ManyToOne` and so on.

Comment: @axtavt I agree, this is the usual understanding, even though it actually means more than that. I'll edit the answer one more time :-)